# No symbol info on profiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, code-analyst

When I use g++ with -g on, AMD CodeAnalyst shows no Symbol information, and Very Sleepy crashes. However, if I compile it without debug information, Very Sleepy runs but of course, no symbols.

I tried to use MSVC and it works perfectly fine, all symbols are there. However I don't want to use it. I wonder why g++ has such an issue.

I use g++ version 4.7.2, VC10 MSVC compiler, CodeAnalyst 3.4.1037.838, Very Sleepy 0.82. Pretty much everything is up to date.

Thanks!

*Edit:* I created a hello world project

```
void hede()
{
    while(1);
}

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    hede();
    return 0;
}
```

Very sleepy crashes and CodeAnalyst still have no symbols. I suspect a bug here?
[image]

Comment: Don't you need `-pg` for profiling?

Comment: Most profilers say -g is enough. I tried -pg as well but the same result.

Comment: Do you turn off optimization? It makes much more debug info, and I remember that for some options it is not even guaranteed to work reliably with -g. Try gdb or perf, do they show symbols?

Comment: Do you use g++ on linux or windows? VerySleepy is win-only, right?

Comment: @queen3 optimization level is -O0. GDB shows symbols, no problem with that. I use Windows btw. Does MSVC work with Linux?

Comment: No MSVC does not, but first I thought you are cross-compiling (and profiling). I wonder if -g on win generates .pdb files. See here: http://www.bytetalk.net/2010/07/how-to-generate-seperate-g-symbol-file.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you generate .pdb files? See http://www.bytetalk.net/2010/07/how-to-generate-seperate-g-symbol-file.html

Comment: I now tried. `Reading symbols from c:\Users\HalilCan\workspace\UCT\Debug\uct.exe...Reading symbols from c:\Users\HalilCan\workspace\UCT\Debug\uct.debug...done.` Didn't help. Very sleepy still crashes, CodeAnalyst have no symbols.